# What is the meaning of the verb 'have'?

Tags: word-usage

I am confused about the meaning of this sentence. In the sentence, what is the meaning of the verb 'have'?

> I have a piece of cake.

Comment: Have you consulted your dictionary?

Comment: @ User178049: There are many definitions of the verb 'have'. I'd like to know which definition is suitable, 'possess' or 'eat'.

Comment: **Context is key**. You should provide it.

Comment: If there is no cotext, it means possess, own or hold, I think. Let me know your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

To properly understand the meaning of a word you really need some context, so let's imagine situations to help contrast the uses of the verb and why people understand *I have a piece of cake* as *I possess a piece of cake*.

- **situation 1**
  I am visiting a friend at his house, and he offers me a cup of tea. I tell him I'm hungry, then he might tell me:

  > I have a piece of cake, you can have that.

  It means **he has** (in his possession) a piece of cake in his house and if I am hungry I can **have it** (eat it).
- **situation 2**
  I'm sitting at home, my mother comes in and asks me if I want anything to eat, I might tell her:

  > I'm fine, I'm having a piece of cake.

  It means I am eating a piece of cake as I am answering her.

Without context we will understand:

> I have a piece of cake.

as meaning "I have a piece of cake in my possession". It is a simple present, it expresses **a situation, something that is true at the moment I am saying it** but not an action taking place.

If we want "have" to mean "eat" in a present situation we would use the -ing form of the verb in the present to express there is **an action taking place**:

> I'm having a piece of cake.

Comment: But the big question is, can you have your cake and eat it too?

Comment: @fixer1234 But we all wish we could, don't we?

Comment: "I have a piece of cake" could refer to eating the cake if context makes clear we're talking about a habitual action. Example: "Q: What do you usually have after dinner? A: I have a piece of cake".

Answer (score 0):

based on your example, the 'have' means possess, own or hold. 'eat' is too far from its meaning.

Another example:

> Mark had a new car and a house